# Servlet filter redirect, url not changed

Tags: java, session, servlets, servlet-filters

I'm having a problem with my authentication filter. When the filter redirects to the login page, all the previous page (main page) is displayed in the login page.
If I go to the login page manually it works fine.

Here is my filter:

```
    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;

    HttpSession session = req.getSession(false);
    String loginURL = req.getContextPath() + SiteMap.LOGIN_CONTROLLER;
    boolean sessionCreated = session != null && !session.isNew();

    if (sessionCreated) {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    } else {
        res.sendRedirect(loginURL);
    }
```

I also noted that when filter redirects to the login page the URL in browser bar stays the same. The main problem is that I get content from other page in the login page. I don't know where is the problem.

Comment: If you already had access to a page, then `getSession` will always return a "not new session" which will leads to the first case of your `if` statement.

Comment: I think `if` statements works fine, because it redirects correct, the only problem is that URL is not changed to "/login".

Comment: OK, is there any other servlet filters before this filter? No filters should have written on the response otherwise the `sendRedirect` can't work.

Comment: No this is the only filter. I have: `res.sendRedirect(loginURL);` How do you mean written on the response? I was helping with this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info)

Comment: @extra90 How you are calling the other page from login page..?? is it using request.forward or redirect, possible can you post the code for that

Comment: @Looser `response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + SiteMap.HOME_CONTROLLER);`

Answer (score 4):

Changing the URl in browser did not depends on filter but it depends on how you are calling the page/servlet. You can call your servlet/jsp in two ways

1. [RequestDispatcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html) : Transfers the control to other under the same request (Same URL)
2. [Send Redirect](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendRedirect%28java.lang.String%29) : Initiates a new request (New Url)

   Note : All that filter will do is a validation for the request

Answer (score 0):

what is the value of loginURL that you are passing . Send a relative path.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190733/java-servlet-filter-redirect-problem?rq=1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190733/java-servlet-filter-redirect-problem?rq=1) I found that I should redirect to the login page directly.

Comment: redirect to /login.jsp

Comment: you can monitor your requests use 'fiddler' and check whats happening

Comment: This is not answer, it should be comment.

Answer (score -2):

I was having the exact same problem.
The real problem is that I and you both forgot to add the following line:

```
response.setContentType("text/html");
```

After adding this line my redirect works fine.  Before this my servlet will stay on the 
same page with a blank page (because nothing has been written to the response oputput stream).

Hope this may help others who is having this problem.  It took me some painful minutes before test this possibility.